# Shell Variables are empty when called in a file name but not when echo'd or called elsewhere

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables

I have 4 shell variables set

```
remote_account="raccname"
remote_machine="server"
First_Name="firstname"
Last_Name="lastname"
```

when I call `remote_account` or `remote_machine` in my script they get used fine

```
echo "What directory shall you choose?"
  read dir
  scp -r ~/csc60/$dir $remote_account@$remote_machine:directoryA
  exit;;
```

but when I call the other two as such

```
echo "What directory shall you choose?"
  read dir
  scp $remote_account@$remote_machine:tars/$Last_Name_$First_Name_$dir.tar.z ~/tars
  exit;;
```

it grabs the tars file from `tars/$dir.tar.z` completely skipping `$Last_Name_$First_Name_`
when I throw an `echo $Last_Name` in it still shows it as "lastname"

Is there some rule using "_" between variables or something, or am I just missing something obvious?

Comment: Hint, check out question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951336/how-to-debug-a-bash-script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_` is a valid character for variable names, therefore you have to qualify which part is the variable.

```
scp "$remote_account@$remote_machine:tars/${Last_Name}_${First_Name}_$dir.tar.z" ~/tars
```

Comment: Ah Thanks so much mate I knew it was something simple

Answer (score 0):

You need to delimit your variable value using  ${}, as  you declared $Last_Name_$First_Name_$dir is  treated as one variable and shell put value for it. As in your case you did not defined value for it . It will be intepreted as "".

use  `${LAST_NAME}_${FIRST_NAME}`

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer, much appreciated